# Receive only sms of a particular format by my application

Tags: android

I am using Brodcast Receiver class to receive sms by my application. I have also given priority to my application in manifest file. I have coded in my application that if a sms is in a particular format then it should load a second screen. It runs fine when sms is of particular format but when i send in any other format since my application has been given higher priority it receives sms first(my assumption) then it generates force close dialog box but the message shows in the notification bar.

What i want is if a sms is of particular format then it should be handled by my application else it should be handled by system ?

My main file is :

```
package com.example.smsapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;




public class SMSApp extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";            
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            //   str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
            //  str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            //   str += "\n";        
        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        //Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String[] msgText;
        msgText=str.split(",");
        if(msgText[0].equals("second"))
        {               
            Intent i = new Intent(context,Second.class);
            i.putExtra("msg",msgText[1]);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
            context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }
    this.abortBroadcast();
}



 }
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.demo.smsapp" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="Second" class=".second"
        android:label="SMSApp">
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SMSApp">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
</uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: first problem is put abortBroadcast in if block where you are starting an new activity and post your logcat for force close

Comment: thanks saurabh for replying . i have put abortBroascast in if block. My Logcat is showing 06-21 11:34:22.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(452): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
06-21 11:34:22.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(452):     at com.demo.smsapp.SMSApp.onReceive(SMSApp.java:46)

Answer (score 1):

In your code these two lines are the culprit

```
msgText=str.split(",");
if(msgText[0].equals("second"))
```

No matter the message contains a comma or not your code checks for that and then in second line you check `msgText` array which is actually **null** if that was not the msg you were expecting, so replace second line with

```
if(msgTxt != null && msgText[0].equals("second"))
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. First time if i run this application its generating force close dialog but after other attempts it started working. It does not show any thing in the logcat

Comment: hmmm sounds bizarre in that case you have to debug the code line by line and check where it fails bcoz without logcat its hard to tell  what causing the problem